# Discord.js: Error telling me the command file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, modulenotfounderror

I was making a discord bot and following Worn Off Keys' videos. On the second episode I ran into an error. I even copied and pasted the code that was on his github, but it still doesn't work. Here are the things I have:

my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')
const command = require('./command')

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is up and running.`)

  command(client, ['ping', 'test'], (message) => {
    message.channel.send('shut up idc')
  })
})

client.login(config.token)
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module './command'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/discord-bot-2/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at /home/runner/discord-bot-2/index.js:5:17
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your index.js or primary JavaScript file for running everything located? I had a similar issue but had to move my bot.js file out of the src folder it was in into the main directory area. The issue was relating to the files accessing via fs, I was able to narrow it down to a file access error, where it wasn't able to pull necessary Discord functions from the main file as it was in another folder instead of the top level for access. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer! I just had to take the command file out of the folder i put it in.